# Converting std::function<void(string, string)> to a generic std::function<void()>

Tags: c++, function, bind, c++11, std

I'm trying somme features of c++0x (under gcc 4.5):

I know it's possible to convert a `std::function<void(string, string)>` to `std::function<void()>`  when arguments are specified at compilation; but is it possible when arguments are submitted at runtime ?

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace placeholders;

class Print{

  public:
    void print1(string s1, string s2){ cout<<"s1 : "<<s1<<" s2 : "<<s2<<endl;}
    void print2(string s1){ cout<<"s1 : "<<s1<<endl;}

};

Print p  =  Print();

function<void(string, string)> f1(bind(&Print::print1, &p, _1, _2));

function<void()> f = f1;
```

I get those errors :

```c
/usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:2103:6:   instantiated from ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor = std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)>, _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {}, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type = std::function<void()>::_Useless]’
../src/Cpp0x_test.cpp:345:34:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:1713:9: error: no match for call to ‘(std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>)>) ()’
/usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:2111:5: note: candidate is: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = void, _ArgTypes = {std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char>}]
```

Actually I need to do :

```c
function<void(string, string)> f1(bind(&Print::print1, &p, _1, _2));
function<void(string)> f2(bind(&Print::print2, &p, _1));

function<void()> fx1 = f1;
function<void()> fx2 = f2;

std::vector<function<void()> > vec;

vec.push_back(fx1);
vec.push_back(fx2);

//then, later

function<void()> call1 = vec[0];
function<void()> call2 = vec[1];

call1("test1", "test2");
call2("test3");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't really make sense.

> I know it's possible to convert a `std::function<void(string, string)>`
>   to `std::function<void()>` when arguments are specified at compilation;
>   but is it possible when arguments are submitted at runtime ?

If you're talking about doing this to set the arguments "at compilation":

```
string arg1,arg2;
function<void()> f = bind(f1,arg1,arg2); // f = [=] { f1(arg1,arg2); };
```

this is actually doing the binding at runtime. Whatever value those arguments have when bind is called, even if they are set at runtime, say, from user input, the calling `f()` will use those runtime values.

Perhaps you mean that the above code binds `f1` to the value of `arg1` and `arg2` at the time bind is called, and that changing the values of the objects used in `bind` later on doesn't affect the values used in calls to `f()`. There's a way around that:

```
string arg1,arg2;
function<void()> f =
  bind(f1,std::ref(arg1),std::ref(arg2)); // f = [&,f1] { f1(arg1,arg2); };
```

This causes f to hold references to the objects instead of just the static value used at the time `bind` is called. You can now assign new values to `arg1` and `arg2` and when `f()` is called the new values will be used. Note that you have to make sure that the references held by `f` remain valid and don't become dangling references so long as `f` can still be called.

```
function<void(string)> foo = [](string s){ cout << s; };
string arg = "Hello,";
function<void()> bar = bind(foo,ref(arg)); // bar = [=,&arg] { foo(arg); };
bar(); // prints "Hello,"
arg = " World!"
bar(); // prints " World!"
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, it solves the vector problem and it's faster than bind(&Print::print1, &p, _1, _2) during the function call; but now I have to store the arguments somewhere and in a generic way, so I don't have to create a class for each combination

Answer (score 2):

Its possible using bind aswell:

```
string arg1, arg2;

function<void()> f(bind(f1, arg1, arg2));

f(); // calls f1(arg1, arg2) with their values at the time of bind
```

Comment: I know, but I need to pass the arguments later (after the bind), hence the _1 and _2 in my code

Comment: @codablank1: if you want to pass them later just call `f1(arg1, arg2)`, if you want to pass them before use my answer... what do you ask for?

Comment: My goal is to initialize the function with bind only ONE time and then calling it thousands of time with different parameters; what you propose is to use bind at each call which is super-costly, do you understand ?

Comment: @codablank1: no it doesn't... you can call `f()` thousands of times after one bind. binds are optimized at compile time so don't think they are costly anyway.

Comment: I don't want to do f(), I want to do 
`function<void(string, string)> f1(bind(&Print::print1, &p, _1, _2));`
and then later `string arg1, arg2;
 for(int i=0; i<10000; ++i) { f(arg1, arg2); }`

Comment: @codablank1: so why don't you?

Comment: because I need to store all these `std::function<void(string, string)>` or `std::function<void(int, int)>` or whatever in a `std::vector`, so they all have to be the same type, that is, `function<void()>`

Comment: @codablank1: so use bind... `vector.push_back(bind(f1, arg1, arg2));`

Comment: @codablank1: First, that's a new question, so you should ask it in a new question. Second, what you want is impossible. You cannot magic arguments into functions, nor should you be subverting the type system in that way. If you need a bunch of callbacks with different parameters, then you should be storing a properly typed list (possibly of `boost::variant`) that gives each function its correct type.

Comment: If you have to stick a `function<void(string,string)>` inside a `vector<function<void()>>` before you've created the objects that you want to pass to the function, it's not going to be possible. The whole point of type safety in C++ is to prevent you from trying to do things like what you want to do, because they're dangerous. Take a step back and see if you can change the program on a different scale.  `vector<function<void()>>` doesn't do what you want directly, so try to find something that directly expresses your idea instead of trying to work around `vector<function<void()>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understand your requirement.

Why don't you just store the arguments in a vector instead of the functions?

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string,std::string>> v;
v.push_back(std::make_tuple("a", "b")); // repeat

// Later that day...
for(auto& t : v) {
    f(get<0>(t), get<1>(t));
}
```